# Tracking mouse movement only works inside specific element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to position a image according to position of my mouse using `onmousemove` and `objectPosition`. I want the top of the viewport to be 0%, and the bottom to be 100%, independent if the person scrolls the page or not. As far I understand, this piece of code should do the trick:

```
window.onmousemove = event => {
  var pos = (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 100
  productImageZoomed.style.objectPosition = '50%' + pos + '%'
}
```

But when I move the mouse over the page, it only detects the mouse movement only inside a specific element, `#image-main`. I have no idea why, I thought that the `window` object would work on the entire viewport.

Relevant HTML snippet:

```
<div id="image">
  <a class="image-zoom">
    <div class="zoomPad">
      <img id="image-main" src="/480-721/somename.png"><!-- mouse movement only detectable inside this element -->
      <figure class="product-image container-zoomed" style="display: none;">
        <img class="product-image image-zoomed" src="/1920-2880/somename.png" style="object-position: 50% 0%;"> <!-- the element to be positioned -->
        <figcaption><span>Click to close</span></figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I have absolutely no clue of what is happening, can anyone help?

Here is my [full JS code](https://pastebin.com/RaXJJ5vR) if you think it's relevant

Comment: Did you try attaching it with document/body element instead of window? Can you check if it behave same?

Comment: I don't see any inherent problem with the onmousemove event listener. Do you get any errors? Try putting a console.log in there and testing if it's truly called upon mousemove. But maybe it's that objectPosition only affects the position of the object within its content-box. That means it can't leave its container. Is the intended effect that the image follows the mouse pointer on the y axis only?

Comment: If I attach it to the document/body, it will behave the same, but also differently. The bottom of the viewport won't be always pos = 100%. It has to be the window.